# I'm getting DatabaseError: Permission denied for my Production app yet my development app works fine

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I know this question has been raised many times but I cannot seem to find an answer that suits my question. So I have an app that writes and reads Realtime firebase database, and the problem is that when I run the app in debug mode i.e when in development phase everything works fine. But when I release the app I get a:

> DatabaseError: Permission denied

Here's my database rule

```
"groups":{
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "$group_id":{
        ".validate":"newData.hasChildren(['name','members', 'owner'])"
    }
  }
```

Here's my database write function

```
public void createChatGroup(final String chatGroupName, Map<String, Integer> members,
    final ChatGroupCreatedListener chatGroupCreatedListener) {

    DatabaseReference newGroupReference = this.appGroupsNode.push();
    String newGroupId = newGroupReference.getKey();

    final ChatGroup chatGroup = createGroupForFirebase(chatGroupName, members);
    chatGroup.setGroupId(newGroupId);

    newGroupReference.setValue(chatGroup, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError == null) {
                Log.d(DebugConstants.DEBUG_GROUPS, "GroupsSyncronizer.createChatGroup:" +
                        " databaseReference == " + databaseReference.toString());

                saveOrUpdateGroupInMemory(chatGroup);

                if (chatGroupCreatedListener != null) {
                    chatGroupCreatedListener.onChatGroupCreated(chatGroup, null);
                }

            } else {
                Log.e(DebugConstants.DEBUG_GROUPS, "GroupsSyncronizer.createChatGroup:" +
                        " cannot create chatGroup " + databaseError.toException());
                if (chatGroupCreatedListener != null) {
                    chatGroupCreatedListener.onChatGroupCreated(null,
                            new ChatRuntimeException(databaseError.toException()));//excetio is being caught here.
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private ChatGroup createGroupForFirebase(String chatGroupName, Map<String, Integer> members) {
    ChatGroup chatGroup = new ChatGroup();
    chatGroup.setName(chatGroupName);
    chatGroup.setMembers(members);
    chatGroup.setOwner(currentUserId);
    chatGroup.setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());
    return chatGroup;
}
```

As the rules suggests, the read operation works fine since i can read contents of the `groups` node meaning the user is signed in sign in id: `PJwESB8OLQXuAiP7sbouMz5C1602`

the write operation doesn't work for release app, with this error..

> W/RepoOperation: setValue at /apps/TukenyaMessenger/groups/-MChzWQKnCI7wem4zH0R failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Also the app logic is you have to sign in and get authenticated to access the activity that has this method
What could be wrong?

***Debug app:***: ***OK***

***Release Version app:***: ***DatabaseError: Permission denied***

Comment: Please edit the question to show proof that the circumstances of your rules are being satisfied.  That is, the user is definitely signed in, and the required data is present under as required by your validation rule.

Comment: I have updated and hope its clearer now

Comment: So you're trying to write values at /apps/X/groups/Y, but your rules only specify "groups"?

Comment: This typically means that ProGuard is changing your data classes in the release version, and they don't fit the security rules anymore. Be sure to check the documentation on configuring ProGuard: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard

Comment: /Y is the push key so in short i want to add groups using a push key to the node groups